# Remove String in SUMIFs Value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs, sumproduct

I've got a Microsoft form feeding into a live Excel document - and I'm trying to make a table on a new worksheet (Form1) that totals certain submissions based on a criteria.  I've been using SUMIFS to count conditionals - but I think because Microsoft Form saves these as 'text' values - all my sums have an apostrophe in front of them and my SUMIFS are totally 0.

This is a version of my set-up:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Yes | '10 |
| C | Ye | '15 |
| G | Yes | '10 |
| A | No | '20 |
| A | Yes | '45 |

A and B are the values that I'm checking meet my condition. In this simplified example I want to sum up the totals (Column C) for every row that has an "A" in Column A and a "YES" in Column B.

My function is: `=SUMIFS(Form1!C:C,Form1!A:A, "A",Form1!B:B,"Yes")`

I'm not 100% it's the ' tripping me up - but fairly confident. I've tried exploring both SUMPRODUCT and trying to use LENS/RIGHT/ETC within the function to remove the first character...but no luck.

Any advice how I could do this without having to modify the original columns (since it's live data coming in via a form?).

Comment: You could create column D like `=NUMBERVALUE(C2)`. Then use `SUMIFS` with that column instead of the original.

Answer (score 1):

As eventHandler mentioned in the comments, `NUMBERVALUE` is the way to go and creating a new column is probably easiest.

But if for whatever reason that is not possible, the below is a workaround:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN("",1,FILTER(A2:C6, A2:A6="A", B2:B6="Yes")), "'", "+")
```

Followed by using this technique: https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/excel-factor-12-secret-evaluate-function

Answer (score 1):

Try-

```
=SUMPRODUCT((--SUBSTITUTE(C1:C5,"'",""))*(A1:A5="A")*(B1:B5="Yes"))
```

If numbers are stored as text then use-

```
=SUMPRODUCT((--(C1:C5))*(A1:A5="A")*(B1:B5="Yes"))
```

[image]